# How to skip out of this loop?

Tags: delphi

This is a sorted listview with 50000 items(strings) in delphi. How to fast search items with same prefixed words and then skip out loop?

The list is like:

```
aa.....
ab cd//from here
ab kk
ab li
ab mn
ab xy// to here
ac xz
...
```

I mean how to fast find and copy items with prefixes of ab and skip out loop. Suppose index of one of ab items is got in a binarysearch. The index of ab cd to ab xy  is got through a binary search.

Thank you very much.

Edit: We thank all for your answers.

Comment: Since you know about using a binary chop to find the first and last elements of the range, you seem to have already answered your own question. What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want something fast, don't store your data in a TListView.

Use a TStringList to store your list, then use a TListView in virtual mode.

Reading from a TStringList.Items[] is many times faster than reading from a TListView.Items[] property.

If you're sure that no void item exist in the list, uses this:

```
procedure Extract(List, Dest: TStrings; Char1, Char2: char);
var i,j: integer;
    V: cardinal;
type PC = {$ifdef UNICODE}PCardinal{$else}PWord{$endif};
begin
  V := ord(Char1)+ord(Char2) shl (8*sizeof(char));
  Dest.BeginUpdate;
  Dest.Clear;
  for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do begin
  if PC(pointer(List[i]))^=V then begin
    for j := i to List.Count-1 do begin
      Dest.Add(List[j]);
      if PC(pointer(List[j]))^<>V then
        break; // end the for j := loop
     end;
     break; // end the for i := loop
  end;
  Dest.EndUpdate;
end;
```

You can use binary search to get it even faster. But with the PWord() trick, on a 50000 items list, you won't notice it.

Note that PC(pointer(List[i]))^=V is a faster version of copy(List[i],1,2)=Char1+Char2, because no temporary string is created during the comparison. But it works only if no List[i]='', i.e. no pointer(List[i])=nil.

I've added a {$ifdef UNICODE} and sizeof(char) in order to have this code compile with all version of Delphi (before and after Delphi 2009).

Comment: Dear A.Bouchez: Thank you so much for so detailed and clear answer.

Answer (score 7):

To stop running a loop, use the `break` command. `Exit` is also useful to leave an entire function, especially when you have multiple nested loops to escape. As a last resort, you can use `goto` to jump out of several nested loops and continue running in the same function.

If you use a `while` or `repeat` loop instead of a `for` loop, the you can include another conjunct in your stopping condition that you set mid-loop:

```
i := 0;
found := False;
while (i < count) and not found do begin
    // search for items
    found := True;
    // more stuff
    Inc(i);
end;
```

Comment: Dear Rob Kennedy: Thank you again for your immediate and clear answer. We did not add found flag, and used 'for ...loop', so of low performance.